# Book about a clairvoyant girl who uses throwing knives

Tags: story-identification, novel

The cover sort of resembles a girl that looks like the live action Harley Quinn in *Suicide Squad* (but this was made before the movie) and she sits in front of a target board. She is clairvoyant and travels with an entertainment/circus group. She rides a motorcycle. And I think in the middle or beginning, she meets a guy and they have some kind of feelings for each other. I read it so long ago though.

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this?

Comment: Is it a fantasy or science fiction story?

Comment: Clairvoyance is fantasy.

Comment: Does this ring any bells? https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/34861563

Comment: Parts of the plot remind me of *[Twilight Eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twilight_Eyes)* by Dean R. Koontz, but the protagonist is male, and the cover doesn't match.

Comment: @JohnRennie I don't see why stories about clairvoyants, psychics, or fortune tellers would automatically be fantasy, any more than stories about piano tuners, poets, or pawnbrokers.

Comment: @user14111 being *a* clairvoyant is different from *being* clairvoyant